# The signature of the error SLR20r3

Tags: c#, .net

After building the project on some machines, you get this error, and no matter whether there framework or not, that's the signature of an error (I'm from Russia Sorry for bad english)

- Problem signature:
- Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
- Problem signature 01: cd all osetia 2013.exe
- Problem signature 02: 2.0.0.0
- Problem signature 03: 52711b0d
- Problem signature 04: System.Windows.Forms
- Problem signature 05: 4.0.0.0
- Problem signature 06: 4ba1e14e
- Problem signature 07: c2a
- Problem signature 08: 36
- Problem signature 09: PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX

I realized the problem was in the component axshockwaveflash, I removed it and it worked now I think I do so that it's always worked. I hope my question helps someone. and my question is changed) so as to make the flash work everywhere?